# Show that if $U$ is an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $U$ is path connected.

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $U$ is an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $U$ is path connected. (Hint:Show that given $x_0 \in U$, the set of points can be joined to $x_0$ by a path in $U$ is both open and closed in $U$.)

as  i found the answer  here [Show that if $U$ is an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $U$ is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319103/show-that-if-u-is-an-open-connected-subspace-of-mathbbr2-then-u-is-pa)   but  i did n't  the  red  line

[image]

Pliz  help me,,,,,,,,

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you not see why the underlined portion shows that A is closed? Do you not know why we want to show that A is closed? Do you not understand why the open ball B has to exist? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to show that $A$ is closed, one way to do so is to show that the complement is open. So, you take some $x\in A^c = U\setminus A$ (the complement in U) and show that there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ small enough so that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq U\setminus A$ (the ball centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$ is contained in $U\setminus A$).